# Oracle to PostgreSQL - what is the equivalent to "tab" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I am converting some stuff from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

I have a statement like this:

```
select * from tab;
```

I am referring to the `tab` here.

For example, `select * from tab` in Oracle provides me with what I assume to be a list of all objects, tables and views; everything.

This does not work in Postgres and I cannot seem to find a suitable replacement.

Comment: *what I assume to be a list of all objects, tables and views* - you mean it's not documented? I found [this from the Oracle 7 reference (1996)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SRF73/ch2a.htm#index0949): *"This view is included for compatibility with Oracle version 5. Use of this view is not recommended."* It was already deprecated in 1996. Let that sink in.

Comment: `select * from pg_tables` or `select * from information_schema.tables`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Oracle view is defined as

```
select o.name,
      decode(o.type#, 2, 'TABLE', 3, 'CLUSTER', 150, 'HIERARCHY', 152, 'ANALYTIC VIEW',
         4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM'), t.tab#
  from  sys.tab$ t, sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" o
  where o.owner# = userenv('SCHEMAID')
  and o.type# >=2
  and o.type# <=5
  and o.linkname is null
  and o.obj# = t.obj# (+)
```

So it lists the tables etc. in the schema with the same name as the user.

You could get something like that from a standard conforming database with

```
SELECT table_name, table_type
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = current_user;
```